# Error Occurred During Flow Action name not found: null. Need to force Class Compilation?

Tags: apex, managed-package, visual-workflow, postinstall, package-install

I've occasionally been running into a problem when installing a managed package I'm creating. A simple Screen Flow where at the end it is using an Action to call into an InvocableMethod I am providing.

Error Occurred During Flow "MyFlow": Action name not found: null

I think I've identified the cause as Salesforce is not compiling the class with the InvocableMethod, as if I go into Setup -> Apex Classes and just look at the class, then re-execute the flow it works fine.

Am I on the right path, and if so are there any tricks to make sure that classes with InvocableMethods are always compiled after installing/updating a package?  I've thought of a few hacky things, but want to see if there is a better approach.

(the hacky idea is simply to reference a static final String in each class during the PostInstall?)

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but I am building a 2nd Gen Package

Comment: Did you find a permanent fix for this yet?

Comment: No, the temporary fix I applied (which worked) was to have the PostInstall class just reference a static final String in the class that wasn't compiling.  That worked until 3 weeks ago, now I'm seeing the error again.  I have a support case open with Partner Support looking into it, will post here when there is a resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a support case opened with Salesforce too. Also, I think this issue is related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302649/packaged-lightning-flow-throws-error-on-load-when-apex-action-is-the-first-eleme

Comment: The Action classes that my flow is breaking on are public instead of global as well (per the issue in the comment).  While not harmful, I'd really rather not have to make them global, I don't want to add noise to my client's orgs!

Comment: I got this update from Salesforce: Root cause: A public apex action was not visible to the flow because the current component context had no ManagedInstalledComponent (with a non-null package ID) for the flow, causing the 2GP same-package visibility check to fail. The package ID of the action was known but there was no corresponding package ID for the calling flow.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it yet?

Comment: Setting all actions to global should fix it, but I'm waiting for a Salesforce fix as I don't want my actions to be available outside of the package (I have a lot, and they aren't useful outside of the package)

Comment: I did make them global and it solved this issue but is leading to compilation issues with interfaces when trying to create subsequent release versions. So, you would be wise to not make them global. Thanks for the response.

Comment: This is the issue I ran into when converted to Global: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HVUeQAO

You won't see this in the version you changed to Global but the next upgradable version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug with the Salesforce Platform that is currently slated to be fixed in Winter 21 release.  They are advising to change the scope of the class to Global as a workaround.

> Root cause: A public apex action was not visible to the flow because
> the current component context had no ManagedInstalledComponent (with a
> non-null package ID) for the flow, causing the 2GP same-package
> visibility check to fail. The package ID of the action was known but
> there was no corresponding package ID for the calling flow.
>
> Our R&D has logged a new bug for your issue. The bug fix should be out in Winter'21 release.
>
> Unfortunately, the only workaround until that time is to change the scope of the class to Global

For anyone coming across this answer later on, be sure to read the comments on the original question. A member points out, that you may have unfortunate side effects by doing this.

Comment: Salesforce has logged the bug here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KSXZQA4  Anyone that comes across this may choose to mark the issue as affecting them.

Comment: Still an issue for me at this time, so just accomplished the workaround of running the corresponding Apex test class.